# Schema PostalAddress and Geo

Tags: schema

I find using Schema quite confusing. I want to check this is the correct way of doing it for adding Address and Geo. I've placed this code within the footer.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <div itemprop="address">

        Address: <span itemprop="streetAddress">Street Address</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">England</span>,
        <span itemprop="postalCode"> E14 8YE</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">GB</span> | 
        Tel: <span itemprop="telephone">00000000000</span>
     </div>
 </div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">

        <div itemprop="geo">
            <meta itemprop="latitude" content="XX" />
            <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-XX" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it looks about right to me except itemprop="address" should be in the first div (e.g. `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemprop="address">`) and you can get rid of that 2nd div. See the error for your code here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool prior to it. You could also nest one inside the other:

```
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    Address: <span itemprop="streetAddress">Street Address</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">England</span>,
    <span itemprop="postalCode"> E14 8YE</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressCountry">GB</span> |
    Tel: <span itemprop="telephone">00000000000</span>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
        <div itemprop="geo">
            <meta itemprop="latitude" content="XX" />
            <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-XX" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If these are part of a place you may want to nest it in a place, or a local business, or a hotel, you may want to nest both of these inside that like the microdata example of http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates